# bash: nested while read & for file in - no output

Tags: bash, while-loop, blast

I have the following file structure:

```
db/organism1.fasta
db/organism1.fasta.nhr
db/organism1.fasta.nin
db/organism1.fasta.nsq
db/organism2.fasta
db/organism2.fasta.nhr
db/organism2.fasta.nin
db/organism2.fasta.nsq
sequences/abc123.faa
sequences/def456.faa
numbers.txt
```

`numbers.txt`

```
abc123
def456
```

Now I want to

1. read in each line of the file `numbers.txt` - each number represents a file in the dir `sequences`
2. take each `*.fasta`file from the dir `db`
3. do something (in this case a blast search of each db against the sequences)
4. output one file for each line in `numbers.txt`

This is my attempt:

```
while read line
   do for file in db/*.fasta
      do tblastn -db $file -query sequences/$line.faa -evalue 1e-10 -outfmt 7 >>$line_blastn.txt
   done
done<numbers.txt
```

But no file is being written. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$line_blastn` is treated as *one* variable. Since that variable was never assigned any value, the output file will be just `.txt`. Files starting with a dot are hidden in Linux and Max OS, therefore you cannot see the output file.

Write `... >> "${line}_blastn.txt"` to use just `line` as a variable.

Comment: thank you. A good practice when using variables is to write them this way? "${variable}"

Comment: Quoting variables is always a good idea. Unquoted variables are problematic if their contents can contain spaces or special symbols like `*`. Using curly braces `{}` does not hurt, but I'm often too lazy to write them when I don't need them.

Comment: The fundamental difference: To know whether you can omit quotes, you have to know the content of the variable (rarely the case); To know whether you can omit curly braces, you have to know the the name of the variable (always the case, except when working with `eval`).